# Spring Tool Suite/Eclipse: Missing Spring Documentation: Can it be installed?

Tags: eclipse

**Spring Tool Suite**

**Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE**

**Build Id: 201210061306**

**Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0.RELEASE - based on Eclipse Juno 4.2.1**

**spring-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e4.2-win32-installer.exe**

**Microsoft Windows XP Pro**

Hi. I just installed the above.

When I go to Help | Help Contents there are sorts of useful "books" explaining the basics of how to do things.

One of those is titled **"Spring Documentation"**

However, all of the branches and nodes are blank.
I either get 404 errors when pressing on them or place holder web pages.

Is there any way I can install that missing tutorial into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

**From the Spring web board:**

```
You are right, the Spring documentation part in the help contents of STS is broken (this needs to be fixed by us). In the meantime I would like to recommend you our "Getting Started" collection of links here:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124335-Getting-Started

As well as the official "Getting started" section on the web here:

http://www.springsource.org/get-started

It also contains the links for the official Spring framework documentation.
```